# CEF 3 workaround missing features

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I'm building an application that is using CEF 3 (version 1650) in WPF (meaning I'm using OSR mode) using Xilium.CefGlue as a wrapper.

After a lot of research I've found several features I can't get to work nor workaround:

- **Focus Management** - I need to tell when the last focusable item in the page lost focus due to a Tab press (or the first item due to Shift+Tab)
- **Javascript Alerts** - I got them to work for standard schemes, but not for custom schemes (also found a bug regarding it). I'm looking for a way around it.
- **Favicons** - Seems CEF3 did not implement favicon support. I guess I can look for favicon.ico in the root directory for standard schemes, but what about favicons linked in the HTML itself?
- **User Permission Notification** - I only found permission request events for geolocation request, but I also need for other things such as getUserMedia. Any idea how?
- **Zoom** - This one works except for getZoomLevel, that for some reason always returns zero. Does anyone knows why or how to get around it considering it does remember each page's last zoom?
- **Process Model** - I can't get multiple browser windows opened manually (that is, not via javascript's `openWindow`) all with the same custom scheme to open in the same render process (already tried all different process model parameters I know of). As far as I understand, it should be possible. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Still unconstructive. I already have all of these. I have working OSR, I have working popup windows which is something I didn't even mentioned. I do run getZoomLevel on the UI thread and still getting zero, unless I need to sync to a different UI thread and if this is the case - how? Please read again my question more thoroughly. Sending me to do *more* research is not a good answer.

Comment: I have the same "getZoomLevel always returns zero" issue, maybe because "This method can only be called on the UI thread. "

Answer (score 0):

- **Focus Management** is it [OnTakeFocus](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefFocusHandler.html#OnTakeFocus) you are looking for?
- **Favicons** has an open enhancement issue in the CEF project

Comment: I tried using `OnTakeFocus` but it never gets fired.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds their way to this question, [favicon support is now available](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/964/cef3-add-favicon-support) in the official CEF builds.